# XPages Split value in bound field

Tags: xpages-ssjs

If I have used Simple Data Binding to bind a field in a data source and I get to see the full value of that field. What I want to do is split that value up and then only show part of it to the user. For instance the field stores the value of a combo box which has "1~Hello" in it and the bind shows me "1~Hello", but I only want to see "Hello". Is there some way like a converter to do this or is the only way via a JavaScript bind with a split("~")[1] on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. It seems like you are working with a structured list so using a ComboBox, radioButtonGroup or CheckBoxGroup control would allow for definition of an alias in the values. But it you really want a textbox binding, then build a custom converter...

```
<xp:inputText
    id="inputText1"
    value="#{viewScope.demo}">
    <xp:this.converter>
       <xp:customConverter>
        <xp:this.getAsObject><![CDATA[#{javascript:
if ("Hello".equals(value)) return "1- Hello";
//do other tests and edits
return value
}]]></xp:this.getAsObject>
    <xp:this.getAsString><![CDATA[#{javascript:
if ("1-Hello".equals(value)) return "Hello";
//do other tests and edits
return value
}]]></xp:this.getAsString>
       </xp:customConverter>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

Comment: Thanks /Newbs. I'll give this a go Monday :o)